# How to catch changing of property in model by another property in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties, prism

I have a problem with the extension of the model. I need to update AngleNegative property in same time as property Angle updated in Station class. AngleNegative property data based on data from Angle as you can see in example. I can't modify Station model, because it used in another VM and have same problem but with another properties. What solution of this can be?

```
  public class Station : BindableBase, IStation
     {
        //some properties
        .
        .
        .

        private int _angle;

        public int Angle
        {
            get => _angle;
            set => SetProperty(ref _angle, value);
        }
     }


public class ViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private Station _station;
        public Station Station
        {
            get => _station;
            set => SetProperty(ref _station, value);
        }

        //delete this property duplicate and base on Station.Angle
        private int _angle;
        public int Angle
        {
            get => _angle;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _angle, value);
                AngleNegative = value - 180;
            }
        }

        private int _angleNegative;

        public int AngleNegative
        {
            get => _angleNegative;
            set => SetProperty(ref _angleNegative, value);
        }
    }
```

I think i can inherit VM from IStation, but its a lot of code duplicate after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it by having a method on the ViewModel that listens for `PropertyChanged` events on its `Station`, like this:

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private Station _station;
    public Station Station
    {
        get => _station;
        set => SetProperty(ref _station, value);
    }

    private int _angleNegative;
    public int AngleNegative
    {
        get => _angleNegative;
        set => SetProperty(ref _angleNegative, value);
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Station.PropertyChanged += Station_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Station_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Angle")
        {
            AngleNegative = Station.Angle - 180;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that good idea! I try it befor, and its not work couse it must subscribe in set of Station property(i link object to property). Thanks man!